# Android Internal Object Storage

Tags: android, object, storage

I am trying to save ArrayLists(ArrayOne, ArrayTwo, and ArrayThree) of EditText's to the internal storage. As commented, it clearly shows that it attempts the save, but I never get another TOAST after that. Any help as of why it doesn't show "Save completed" or any error is appreciated.

```
public void save(Context c)
{
    String fileName;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Attempting Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//THIS SHOWS
    if(semester.getText().toString().length() == 0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(c, "Please enter a filename", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        fileName = "test.dat";
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try 
        {
            fos = this.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(ArrayOne);
            oos.writeObject(ArrayTwo);
            oos.writeObject(ArrayThree);
            Toast.makeText(c, "Save Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //THIS NEVER SHOWS
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Could not find " + fileName + " to save.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (oos != null)
                    oos.close();
                if (fos != null)
                    fos.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            { /* do nothing */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello did you try debuging?  Does it show "Could not find "??

Comment: I did try debugging, nothing shows after the "Attempting save". I don't know where the code goes from there.

Comment: Try debugging. If you debug it you won't need any help from other to solve this. Just track where your code is going and you are done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the EditText class is not serializable

If you debug and put a break point at on the printStackTrace and examine the IOException it will tell you that

```
catch (IOException e
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Classes have to use "implements Serializable" in order for them to be written out as objects, which EditText does not have.

You can not extend the class and add the serializable tag either because the underlying class will still throw the exception.

I suggest you either serialize the data via your own class or save whatever you are trying to do with some other method.

Comment: could I just make an ArrayList of strings that contain the text from the EditText's... are strings serializable? Thank you

Comment: @Andrew - Yes base types should serialize fine, strings can be serialized

Comment: Ok, could you point me somewhere that would explain how to "serialize the data via my own class"

Comment: @Andrew, take a look at the extended answer above, but remember if you put any type of non-serializable object in your class your going to get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is beings swallowed in your first Try block because you're only catching FileNotFound and IOException - just for debugging purposes you could catch the generic Exception and printout the stacktrace.

If it also helps this is what I do:

```
java.io.File file = new java.io.File("/sdcard/mystorage/ArrayOne.bin");
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)));
out.writeObject(obj);
out.close();
```

Best

-serkan

Answer (score 0):

If nothing shows after the "Attempting save" you´re getting some exception in this block

```
 catch (IOException e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

And you´re not viewing it in any Toast. Also you can be here in this way doing nothing with your exception:

```
 catch (Exception e)
        { /* do nothing */ }
```

Instead of toasting your messages.. try to use LogCat for debbugging, is easy to use and also you don't need to put toast code in your code. Tell me how is going.